# Header overflows with the content on iPad portrait mode

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad

The url is here http://teothemes.com/wp/viewpoint/. If you'll scroll a little bit to the content areas, the text will overflow with the header area, but once you stop scrolling, it dissapears. I tried editing the z-index, setting a background-color(thought it's because of the loading speed of the images), but it still doesn't work at all. This issue is related to ONLY iPad portrait mode and it works fine on any other browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile safari can have this effect when the Position property is not set correctly.
Try setting the overlapping div to:

```
Position: relative;
```

Again it's hard to say what elements property is not set correctly with no example code, but if you play around you will get there.